# How to inject dependencies in an Angular child class?

Tags: angular, angular8

This is the first time i've extended someone elses class in Angular 8 and i can't get my head around how to inject something into the constructor of the child class.

For example, if i have a parent and a child:

```
export class TestParent
{

}

export class TestClass extends TestParent
{

    constructor(api: ApiService)
    {
        super();
    }

}
```

The injection doesn't work and gives errors because the parent class doesn't have the service injected. So i tried adding it to the parent as well, but i then just get more problems. The service injects ok but the dependencies the service relies on then don't become injected like they normally do in the services contstrucor.

There must be some way to do this?

Basically i'm using ng-chat module and you have to create an adapter class that extends the main adapter. Inside my adapter i need to make api calls using my ApiService but i can't seem to inject the service into my adapter class.

Comment: Is the TestClass a service or a component or a plan class?

Comment: Is these classes inject-able of we need to create a object by newing them

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting the dependency to parent class from child class.

```
export class TestParent {
   constructor(api: ApiService) {}
   
   makeAPiRequest() {
     this.api.makeRequest();
   }
}

export class TestClass extends TestParent {

    constructor(api: ApiService) {
        super(api);
    }

}
```

Comment: in case you are getting errors while trying to inject dependency to parent class, please post the error